# Are there any good editors for Lisp programming, other than Emacs?

Tags: emacs, text, editor, lisp, notepad++

I'm looking for an alternative, since I find emacs difficult to use. I'd rather use an editor that supports all the usual shortcuts I'm used to, such as arrow keys to move the cursor around, CTRL+SHIFT+RightArrow to select the next word, etc.

Basically, I don't want to have to relearn all my familiar shortcuts just so I can use emacs.

Can anyone recommend a suitable editor?

Another thing - Notepad++ supports LISP syntax coloring, but it doesn't have an integrated LISP console like emacs does. Would it be fine to just have a Notepad++ window and a Command Line window open, side-by-side, and use the command-line whenever I want to run my program?

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting question is "Why did you want to use Emacs in the first place?" If you did decide to use it, you could configure the key commands to work however you wanted.

Comment: I suspect, since it based heavily on LISP, it knows a lot about the language constructs (for syntax coloring and such).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [LispIDE](http://www.daansystems.com/lispide/). It's kind of rudimentary but may improve things a bit for you.

Comment: Fantastic! Much better than using Emacs IMO.

Comment: I prefer both Notepad++ and Sublime because it supports automatic indenting.

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, the arrow keys should work just fine on Emacs. (Emacs die-hards will tell you Ctrl-f/b/p/n are preferable, but you don't have to listen to them.) If they don't work by default, something is wrong.

Recent versions of Emacs come with cua-mode, which will make all the other common shortcuts like Ctrl-x/c/v for cut-copy-paste, shift-arrows to select, and so on work as well. If they don't work by default, type "M-x (that's Alt-x on most keyboards) cua-mode".

In general, if you want a particular keystroke to invoke a certain function, then type M-x global-set-key [hit Return] [hit the keystroke] [type name of function], e.g. M-x global-set-key RET [hit the down arrow] next-line RET.

Emacs was made for Lisp by Lisp programmers, and it is the best editor for Lisp simply on account of having been the standard Lisp editor for decades and having every idea for improvement been implemented.

Answer (score 8):

Use [DrScheme](http://www.drscheme.org/). It has got all of the standard keybindings that you might expect. [Here](http://www.wisdomandwonder.com/article/139/working-with-drscheme-372) are my notes on using it. Yes, it is built for Scheme, but maybe it would work well for you.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just emacs you want to use, it's also SLIME. SLIME will let you connect to a Lisp REPL (running the Swank back-end). You can connect to a server process and start interacting with it. [Take a look at the SLIME homepage](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/)

Answer (score 4):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) programmers editor has a configurable syntax highlighter so it should be possible to configure it for Lisp highlighting.

[Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) even has a **Emacs keyboard emulation** mode and is **fully scriptable**, but unfortunately it is not scriptable in Lisp ;)

**Edited:** In response Luís Oliveira comments: *He's looking for a Lisp IDE.*

Zeus does have project/workspace management, compiler/linker/tool support, class browsing, code completion, integrated version control, just like a lot of IDEs.

But Zeus is more than an IDE because it provides a lot of the functionality of an IDE without being tied to any one particular language, in fact just like Emacs.

Comment: The OP is not looking for syntax highlighting, that's the easy part. He's looking for a Lisp IDE.

Comment: He also says "Notepad++ supports LISP syntax coloring, but it doesn't have an integrated LISP console like emacs does." What's with the name calling?

Comment: A Lisp IDE without connection to the REPL is a bit pointless.

Answer (score 3):

I tried for long to find a good editor for my scheme code besides emacs, but even with emacs tringer foubles, it was still the best.  jEdit was the second best, but its kind of like saying that the choices between cake, sawdust and dirt, the sawdust was second best.

Emacs with paredit mode just **owns** for structured editing of s expressions.  Add to that the highlight parens mode, and it gets even better.

The thing about using emacs, is that the editors extensions language is lisp, so it is a great way to learn lisp.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850/getting-started-with-lisp

One thing it mentions is [CUSP](http://sergeykolos.com/cusp/intro/) which runs inside Eclipse.

Also if you are doing Scheme (you don't say which Lisp you are referring to), I second the recommendation of DrScheme.

Comment: It's very similar. Most people mean Scheme when they say LISP.

Comment: Scheme is a Lisp dialect with an emphasis on functional programming.

Comment: Scheme is a Lisp dialect.  It lends itself to functional programming quite well, but it is method agnostic.

Comment: Even Logo is Lisp, but nobody edits Logo in Emacs...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that nearly anyone that programs LISP will use emacs.  You may be putting yourself at a disadvantage if you ever have to work with real LISP programmers.

Additionally, a good programmer should not be tied to any one editor.  Learn to deal without Windows-based key acceleration.

Comment: No, definitely not "nearly anyone" uses Emacs for Common Lisp nowadays. 

And one is neither putting himself at a disadvantage when having to work with "real Lisp programmers" [casing changed for modernity's sake], as I can tell from my own experience as a Vim Lisper who's worked with Emacs users.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [CUSP](http://www.bitfauna.com/projects/cusp/), which has been mentioned, there's also [ABLE](http://phil.nullable.eu/), a relatively simple Lisp editor with REPL integration and stuff.  Personally, I don't have experience using it as I'm happy with SLIME.

Answer (score 1):

I'm undoubtedly a little late on this, but plain old vi(1) --- regular legacy vi --- works quite well, with paren matching and at least some basic s-exp stuff.  Set up your EXRC to use

```
:set ai lisp aw
```

It's not SLIME, but it's something.

Comment: Yes, you also can use vim :set sm

Answer (score 1):

Some commercial Lisp systems (Allegro CL, LispWorks, Corman CL) are coming with their own editors. Typically one can choose between platform specific keybindings and Emacs-like keybindings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, I would recommend Aquamacs, which is a beginner-friendly version of GNU-emacs, and therefore has all the power of emacs, while still offering "standard" copy-paste, save and other features, including normal file dialogs and windows.

Answer (score 0):

There are those that say there are no good editors for **anything**, other than emacs.  I'm sure you'll find a few of them here (although I'm a vim fan).

The vim macro language is a powerful one which can let you run external programs (including the one in the current edit buffer).

But, if you're used to Notepad++, you'll probably find it as hard to move to vim as you would to emacs, so maybe your proposed solution is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

try McCLIM, newlisp

http://www.cliki.net/IDE

Answer (score 0):

> Another thing - Notepad++ supports
>   LISP syntax coloring, but it doesn't
>   have an integrated LISP console like
>   emacs does. Would it be fine to just
>   have a Notepad++ window and a Command
>   Line window open, side-by-side, and
>   use the command-line whenever I want
>   to run my program?

Yes! Take advantage of ASD though and just reload the system after making changes.

Don't restart your image every time.

Do try Eclipse/Cusp or Limp if you want REPL integration, though.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs is not as weird and unfriendly as it once was. Depending on what platform you prefer, there are two modern, updated Emacs implementations with more familiar user interfaces.

If you are a Mac OS X user, the more polished is [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/):

If you prefer Linux or Windows, then there is Xah Lee's [ErgoEmacs](http://ergoemacs.org/):

Both are FOSS and free to download.